# How to calculate values inside dynamic created elements

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am creating input fields inside HTML table on click of button and want to do some calculations,but it is not happening as I want, I am working on vue.js

**What I have done**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: []

    }
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      this.tableDatas.push({
        itemname: 'item',
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 0,
      });
    },
    calculateQty(tableData) {
      let Amount = parseFloat(tableData.quantity) * parseFloat(tableData.sellingprice)

      if (!isNaN(Amount)) {
        tableData.amount = Amount.toFixed(2);
        console.log(tableData.quantity)

      }
    },
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.5/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(tableData, k) in tableDatas" :key="k">

        <td>
          <input class="form-control" readonly v-model="tableData.itemname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control text-right" type="text" min="0" step=".01" v-model="tableData.quantity" v-on:keyup="calculateQty(tableData)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control text-right" type="text" min="0" step=".01" v-model="tableData.sellingprice" v-on:keyup="calculateSPrice(tableData)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="text" min="0" step=".01" v-model="tableData.amount" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when I create a row I want to calculate amount for each corresponding row I have created, And I am doing that using plain `javascript`,The next thing is to suppose there are 5 rows created I want to show total amount in total Row's Amount field

when I am typing anything inside  quantity field on key up I am doing calculations but when I press `back space` the amount is not going to set to 0 I have to type 0 for that, by default quantity field is having value as 1.
I am doing it all with plain `javascript` I just want to know how to do it with vue.js to make it more easier and less complex

Comment: @Lewis No I have already worked in vue.js, as my dynamic table creations is in vue only, I have already made a start, I have posted where I have been stuck

Comment: Looking closer at your question, I've removed my previous comment. However, I still don't 100% understand what you want. Are you just trying to set the input to 0 when empty or is there more to it? _" I am doing it all with plain javascript I just want to know how to do it with vue.js to make it more easier and less complex"_ is adding unnecessary confusion I think.

Comment: @Lewis I ant to calculate total rows amount into the input field below which could be done by `computed properties`, the line is because I am using plain javascript to achieve that thing, just want to know how to do that using vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      this.tableDatas.push({
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 0
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas
        .map(tableData => {
          return tableData.amount = (
            parseFloat(tableData.quantity) *
            parseFloat(tableData.sellingprice)
          );
        })
        .reduce((total, current) => total + current, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(tableData, k) in tableDatas" :key="k">
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" readonly v-model="tableData.itemname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="tableData.quantity" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="tableData.sellingprice" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="tableData.amount" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit:

I let my imagination run wild and I did it also with components:

```js
Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    amount: Number
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      this.tableDatas.push({
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 55
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {amount}) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: hey you get it wrong `quantity * selling price = amont` of that row then again new row same thing an the sum of amount of row one and row to = total Row's amount.

Comment: @dheerajkumar I do not understand what is the matter? For each row of the data table, I count `quantity * selling price`, and return to the table whose sum is calculated by `reduce`. Is this exactly what you are asking for?

Comment: And that was what you meant. I didn't notice it. Corrected. It is not a clean solution, but it works. Definitely for such things, I suggest creating components (form elements).

Comment: @dheerajkumar Is this the solution you expected? If so, mark it as a solution. It would be nice if you also give upvote.